Vault doesn't load correctly. [PaperSpigot 1.21.1]
So I'm writing a minecraft plugin for Paper 1.21.1. The concept is a PaySign, so you're able to place a special sign that when you right click it, it sends Money to another player.
I added dependencies for VaultAPI and depend: Vault into my plugin.yml file but it still doesnt work.
Other plugins:

AuthMe-5.6.0
EssentialsX-2.21.0-dev
LogBlock-1.19.0.0
SkinsRestorer latest
Vault 1.17.3

Resulting Stacktrace after starting the Server:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/milkbowl/vault/economy/Economy
        at paysignssr-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/com.github.hc12.paysignssr.PaySignSSR.setupEconomy(PaySignSSR.java:27) ~[paysignssr-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at paysignssr-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/com.github.hc12.paysignssr.PaySignSSR.onEnable(PaySignSSR.java:18) ~[paysignssr-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:288) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:202) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:640) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:589) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:754) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:516) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:329) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1215) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:330) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.entrypoint.classloader.PaperPluginClassLoader.loadClass(PaperPluginClassLoader.java:146) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.entrypoint.classloader.PaperPluginClassLoader.loadClass(PaperPluginClassLoader.java:107) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-52-e08e667]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[?:?]
        ... 14 more

Codebase
PaySignSSR.java
package com.github.hc12.paysignssr;

import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredServiceProvider;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class PaySignSSR extends JavaPlugin {

    // Declare the econ variable here
    private static Economy econ = null;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SignHandler(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new SignClickEvent(), this);
        getServer().broadcastMessage("PaySign Loaded");

        if (!setupEconomy()) {
            getLogger().severe("Vault dependency not found or no economy plugin available! Disabling plugin.");
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy() {
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null) {
            return false;
        }
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Economy> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);
        if (rsp == null) {
            return false;
        }
        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ != null;
    }

    public static Economy getEconomy() {
        return econ;
    }
}

SignHandler.java
package com.github.hc12.paysignssr;

import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.SignChangeEvent;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;


public class SignHandler implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent event) {
        String firstLine = event.getLine(0);
        String secondLine = event.getLine(1);
        String thirdLine = event.getLine(2);
        String fourthLine = event.getLine(3);

        if (firstLine.equalsIgnoreCase("[PaySign]") && secondLine != null && thirdLine != null) {
            event.setLine(0, "§2[PaySign]");
            String target = secondLine;
            Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(thirdLine);
        }
    }
}

SignClickEvent.java
package com.github.hc12.paysignssr;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.block.Sign;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;

public class SignClickEvent implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void OnPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Block clickedBlock = event.getClickedBlock();
            if (clickedBlock != null && (clickedBlock.getType() == Material.OAK_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.OAK_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.BIRCH_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.BIRCH_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.SPRUCE_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.SPRUCE_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.JUNGLE_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.JUNGLE_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.ACACIA_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.ACACIA_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.DARK_OAK_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.DARK_OAK_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.CRIMSON_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.CRIMSON_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.WARPED_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.WARPED_WALL_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.MANGROVE_SIGN ||
                    clickedBlock.getType() == Material.MANGROVE_WALL_SIGN)) {
                Sign sign = (Sign) clickedBlock.getState();
                String[] lines = sign.getLines();
                if (lines[0] == "§2[PaySign]" && lines[1] != null && lines[2] != null) {
                    Player player = event.getPlayer();
                    Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(lines[1]);
                    Double amount = Double.parseDouble(lines[2]);
                    Integer time = Integer.parseInt(lines[3]);
                    if (time == null) {
                        time = 1000;
                    } else {
                        time = time * 1000;
                    }
                    Economy econ = PaySignSSR.getEconomy();
                    if (econ.getBalance(player) < amount) {
                        player.sendMessage("§cJesteś za biedny!");
                    } else {
                        econ.withdrawPlayer(player, amount);
                        econ.depositPlayer(target, amount);
                        player.sendMessage("§aZapłaciłeś " + ChatColor.GOLD + amount + "§agraczowi " + ChatColor.WHITE + target);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.hc12</groupId>
    <artifactId>paysignssr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>paysignssr</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.MilkBowl</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

plugin.yml
name: paysignssr
version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
main: com.github.hc12.paysignssr.PaySignSSR
api-version: '1.21'
depend: Vault

I have tried reinstalling Vault and checked out some other things but nothing worked :/

Welcome on Stack Overflow. Can you show your plugin.yml file?

name: paysignssr
version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
main: com.github.hc12.paysignssr.PaySignSSR
api-version: '1.21'
depend: Vault

Don't add code or configurations in comments. [edit] the question.

@HC12 can you try to set in your plugin.yml: depend: [ Vault ] (with [ ] ) ?

@Elikill58 i tried that and it didn`t change anything, still the same error :/

I just copied your code and it works for me. Are you sure vault is well installed with fine version? Are you sure it doesn't have error on startup? You said 1.17.3 but it's 1.7.3, is that a typo?

@Elikill58 Yes, im using paper for mc 1.21.1, vaultApi od 1.7.3 when i'm back home im gonna check one more time and fix the typos

did you find something?

The depend key in the plugin.yml file only allows an array input.
Replace depend: Vault with depend: [Vault] to solve your problem.
Also: Make sure Vault is also being loaded correctly and provide complete logs as well as the output for /plugins to see if the Plugins are loaded correctly, if Vault does not load, that would explain your issue.
